# How to Intercept / Read Response Body in Swift for Any HTTP Call In the App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlconnection

My app has some frameworks that make HTTP API calls in the app. I am not able to modify frameworks but I do want to read the responses the app receives. I tried something like this but it prints nothing:

```
  private func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: URLResponse!) {
        print("RESPONSE IS \(String(describing: response))")
  }
```

Is there an easy way to intercept HTTP response for any call fired from the app using Swift so I can read response body?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "intercept"? And what exactly you want to intercept? To read/intercept a response you can use Charles Proxy, for example. A Swift solution could be to simply use `URLSession` methods or whatever other lib you want.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can't even be sure how these frameworks send their http calls. There is definitely no "easy" way.

Comment: @valcanaia Thanks for advice. Not with Charles but inside the app code during runtime I want to retrieve some data from response so the app behaves accordingly.  I'll look into `URLSession`

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your own subclass of URLProtocol and register it with the app. Thereafter all connections initialized from the App will make use of this protocol, and you will be able to read/intercept whichever request you want, even can block request if you intend to.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlprotocol

Answer (score -2):

You can use *[Alamofire](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire)* - here's a request example retriving JSON data:

```
 Alamofire.request("http://myurl.com", method: .get, parameters:
 parameters).responseJSON {

             response in
             if response.result.isSuccess {

                 print("Success! Got the data")

                 let dataSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                 print(dataJSON)

             }else{

                 print("Error \(response.result.error)")

             }             
        }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.